# merge accounts form keeps trying to merge the wrong way

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm trying to merge the account https://money.stackexchange.com/users/57590/rpresser into the account https://money.stackexchange.com/users/57592/ross-presser. Both accounts are using the same email (57590 was accidentally created as a guest post). I've tried three times now, and each time it offers to merge them the wrong way:

> Thank you for confirming ownership of your accounts. The account Ross Presser will be removed, and all rep and votes will be transferred to account rpresser as a result of this merge.

Each of the three times I got this message, I have avoided pressing OK, because I don't want "Ross Presser" account (connected to other SE network accounts) removed.

I want rpresser removed and Ross Presser to gain its question. How do I convince the system to do it?

I apologize if Meta is the wrong place to ask for this help; if so, say so and I will promptly delete this question.

Comment: You know, the accounts on your different SEs have different numbers.  It's not the “same” account connected to other SEs, just linked accounts.  If the merge preserves the linkage, it doesn't matter which number it keeps *here*.